# CSS to fit content height but not go off screen

Tags: css

I would like to define a div that has the following characteristics:

1. It expands vertically to fit content.
2. It does not expand off screen but rather shows a scrollbar.

I'm using this "List Group" example here as a base:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/sidebars/

However, when I add something above the scrolling list, the list doesn't shrink down vertically to accommodate the header, it just pushes the scroll list down and now I have two scroll bars: one for the screen (since the whole list got pushed down) and another scroll bar for the list box (since its still the same size and has to scroll its internal elements).

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <div>
        <header class="mb-1 py-2 w-100">
            <div class="align-items-center container-fluid d-grid gap-3" style="grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;">
                <div class="m-0 p-0">
                    <div class="align-items-center d-flex mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-dark text-decoration-none" href="/">
                        <span class="fs-4">Task Administration</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="m-0 p-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary float-end">Save all changes</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger float-end me-4">Discard all changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="bh-divider"></div>
    </div>
    <main class="d-flex flex-nowrap" >
        <div class="d-flex flex-row" >
            <div class="align-items-stretch bg-white d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0" style="width: 380px;">
                <a class="align-items-center border-bottom d-flex flex-shrink-0 link-dark p-3 text-decoration-none" href="/">
                    <span class="fs-5 fw-semibold">Categories</span>
                    <button class="btn" style="opacity: 0" type="button">Hidden for alignment</button>
                </a>
                <div class="border-bottom list-group list-group-flush scrollarea" id="contentArea">
                    <data-items-list></data-items-list>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

If I don't fix the height on id="contentArea", to something like height:800px, then the list always bumps off the screen and creates 2 scrollbars.

I'd rather not fix the height since different people have different sized screens.

I've been racking my brains trying all sorts of css shenanigans, but nothing seems to work and writing my own javascript to do this seems like a bad idea.

Thanks all for your time and attention.

Comment: Try to create a snippet that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Have it in some code sandbox so that it will be easier for others to troubleshoot & provide you with specific changes. For now, all I can think of is adding no scrollbar to parent container

Comment: Please use the StackOverflow snippet system to add a runnable version so that we can see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I don't have time right now to learn some new system so I'll use my work around for now.  I'm starting to think that Bootstrap and similar frameworks are great in 2 scenarios: 1) you want something very simple to work out of the box 2) you are a css grand master and know all the tricks and hacks.

For me, I'm a CSS novice and I have moderate demands of complexity and it seems these pre-packaged libraries struggle there.  They quickly start to fall apart and rely on highly specialized knowledge of CSS to figure out WTF is going on.

Oh well, you live you learn.